# Transposing a matrix represented as a string?

Tags: java

I have a 25 character long string where every subsequent 5 characters represent a row in the matrix.

```
String matrix="qwsedrhendtedksiehwnehsbt";
```

I am trying to transpose it using a function

```
public String transpose(String str) {

    if (str == null || str.length() == 1 || str.length() == 2) {
        return str;
    } else {
        return str.substring(0, 1) + str.substring(str.length() -1, str.length()) + transpose(str.substring(1, str.length() -1) );
    }
}
```

produces

```
result="qtwbssehdernhwehneditsekd"
```

this isnt the expected result.
the result must be

```
expectedResult="qrtiewheehsedhsenkwbddsnt"
```

I am not able to understand where I am going wrong

Comment: Could you post a sample input / output? Also, what doesn't work?

Comment: "Transpose" means to reflect on the (main) diagonal. First and last element remain in place if elements are stored in a onedimensional array.

Comment: I can't really see how recursion helps you transpose a matrix.

Comment: @PaulBoddington It might: if you swap the first row with the first column and then transpose the remaining submatrix . But I'm not sure that "transposing" is what OP really means.

Comment: @laune That's a good point. It would work if it was actually a `char[][]`, but since it's a `String` of length `25`, a submatrix is not even a substring.

Comment: @PaulBoddington You can handle a x[N][N] stored as an x[N*N]. Just a little index calculation. OP hasn't shown that, though, so I'm still waiting for a confirmation.

Comment: Can you explain what "transpose" means here? I am not smart enough to see how that input leads to that output.

Comment: its a 25 character string representing a 5x5 square matrix. every 5 characters are rows of the matrix.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Basically, picture the 25 characters as a 5x5 matrix. Write the row as columns (symmetry along the first diagonal), flatten that again as 25 characters.

Comment: @Tunaki I get that, but why does the expected result not end in `d`?

Comment: @PaulBoddington because the diagonal elements remain the same even after transposing

Comment: @Rishabh Sorry I was being dense. I misread your incorrect output for the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This transposes a nxn char matrix stored in a string of length n².

```
static String transpose( String s ){
    char[] c = s.toCharArray();
    int n = (int)Math.sqrt(s.length());
    for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i ){
        for( int j = i+1; j < n; ++j ){
            char h = c[i*n+j];
            c[i*n+j] = c[j*n+i];
            c[j*n+i] = h;
        }
    }
    return new String( c );
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, I was stuck in thinking about substringing and recursive function calls

Answer (score 3):

This method works for strings representing square matrices.

```
static String transpose(String s) {
    int n = s.length();
    int m = (int) Math.sqrt(n);
    if (m * m != n)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        sb.append(s.charAt(i * m % (n - 1)));
    sb.append(s.charAt(n - 1));
    return sb.toString();
}
```

This more general version works for strings representing rectangular matrices.

```
static String transpose(String s, int rows, int columns) {
    int n = s.length();
    if (rows * columns != n)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        sb.append(s.charAt(i * columns % (n - 1)));
    sb.append(s.charAt(n - 1));
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Nice! If you use `sb.append(s.charAt(i/m + i%m*m));` in a loop going up to n-1, you can omit the additional append for the last element.

Comment: @laune Good point. You're right there's no reason to deal with the last case differently, but I really like the `% (n - 1)` trick. At first it looks like it can't possibly work.

Comment: Here's another one that works for all elements: (i*m + i/m)%n.

Answer (score 0):

I have an c++ implementation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


char* transpose (const char* matString, unsigned int col, unsigned int row)
{
    char *answer = (char*)calloc(strlen(matString), sizeof(char));

    unsigned int index = 0;

    for(unsigned int i=0;i<col;i++)
   {
        for(unsigned int j=0;j<row;j++)
    {
        answer[index++] = matString[j * col + i];
    }
 }

    return answer;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
printf("%s", transpose("ABCDEF", 3, 2));

    return 0;
}
```

It gives output **ADBECF**

for the program the input matrix was

```
A-B-C
D-E-F
```

After transposition,.it's row will be column & columns will be row

```
A-D
B-E
C-F
```

& the string representation will look like **ADBECF**. For a quick explanation of the matrix transposition can have a look inside [Matrix transposition](http://www.mathwords.com/t/transpose_of_a_matrix.htm)

this is more generalized implementation of your problem specifies. It takes an row & col input for further generalization. Hope it helps you.